# Reset for form not working after search has been done

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to reset the form to blank values in the input textboxes  after the data filled in the textbox have been searched.

```
<form id="myForm" class="mt-5" asp-controller="Leave" asp-action="GetAllLeaves">
    <div class="form group col-md-6">
        <label>Employee </label>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="hidden" id="employeeId" name="employeeId" />
            <input type="text" name="employeeName"  id="employeeName" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilterE"]" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</button>
        <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Reset</button>
</form>
```

I have tried bunch of different javascripts but none of them work after the search has been completed. They work fine before the search button is clicked. I am aware that there are questions already asked about this here and I have tried those codes but they don't work for me.
These are the different codes that I have tried. They don't work after the search button has been hit. Even refreshing the page does not delete the data in the input boxes.

```
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myForm")[0].reset();
        };

       $("#reset").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
        });

        document.getElementById("reset").onclick = () => {
            document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
        };

        let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
        document.getElementById("reset").onclick = () => {
            inputs.forEach(input => input.value ='');
          

        }
```

Comment: `Even refreshing the page does not delete the data in the input boxes.` this is because you submit the form through `get` method, you will see the filter conditions are appended to the url as querystring, when you refresh they are still sent to backend.

Answer (score 0):

in your post method you need to have an IactionResult return type method and then you need to pass property name to `ModelState.Remove` method, not the value.
Either pass the property name in string, eg. `ModelState.Remove("PropertyName");` or in the newer .NET framework, you can use nameof() keyword, eg. `ModelState.Remove(nameof(model.Property));`

Answer (score 0):

The HTMLFormElement.reset() method restores a form element's default values. This method does the same thing as clicking the form's reset button. If a form control (such as a reset button) has a name or id of reset it will mask the form's reset method. It does not reset other attributes in the input, such as disabled.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset.

Your default input value = "@ViewData["CurrentFilterE"]". Reset method restores a form element's default values.

This will help to reset the input:

html:

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="employeeName" id="employeeName"  value="test" />
   <button id="reset" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Reset</button>
</form>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function(e) {
  document.getElementById("employeeName").value = "";
}
```

Comment: sorry it did not work. Thank you explanation. I am new to coding and all these explanations help a lot.

Comment: I know it should be working , but for some reason which I do not understand it is not working for me. Thank you for your effort!!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following

```
        $("#reset").click(function () {
           // this  for normal <input> text box
        $('#employeeName').attr("value", "");
           //this for checkbox
        document.getElementById('searchAprroved').removeAttribute('checked');

        });
```